# Unexpected ! in checking multiple variables

Tags: php

I need to check multiple varibles but I'm getting the following error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/carematch3/includes/user.php on line 42**

LINE 42

```
if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone) !empty($gender) && !empty($dob)) {
                $phaseOne = true;
            }
```

Comment: There's an "and" operator missing `!empty($phone) !empty($gender)`

Comment: `!empty($phone) !empty($gender)`

Comment: oh wow, thanks... how i missed that i will never know!

Comment: @BradFletcher If you have a long code line and there is an error in it you can always split the long code line over multiple lines and so the error message will tell you exactly on what line the error is and then you know better where the error is. Example: `if(!empty($firstname) &&` new line `!empty($lastname) &&` new lines ...

Answer (score -1):

Your code

```
if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone) !empty($gender) && !empty($dob)) {
            $phaseOne = true;
        }
```

My Code :

```
if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone) **&&** !empty($gender) && !empty($dob)) {
            $phaseOne = true;
        }
```

Please check the syntax error in bold correction